Do they make custom acrylic or mineral based counter wash basins?
I am looking for buying this one
https://rubi.ca/en-CA/bathroom/sanitary-wares/RMP1400R
Unfortunately it is 7/8" wider than I need and I am wondering if there are companies that manufacture custom products like this


Have you asked the company if they make different sizes?

yes I just did, waiting for an aswer

If you don't want to grind off 7/8" you can get a custom top; here's an example: https://swanstone.com/custom-vanity

not really. first -the minimum width is 25". Second I could not find an one piece counter and wash basin like above

If min. width is 25" and that is a problem, how wide is your vanity?  Any smaller and it will be hard to fit a sink, and there certainly will not be any room on the side.

19.5". The o e I need to cut is 3/4 wider and it has a sink it is cou ter and sink in one piece

There are custom manufacturers. However you can cut these with a diamond blade in a wet-saw or angle grinder.
Use eye and breathing protection. I used blue tape to mark the line I cut on. Work slowly.  I cut my sink outside. It will make a mess even if the wet-saw is used.

Cutting will cancel any warranty.  Should be the last option if OP cares about warranty/only way.  Wet-saws are messy, dusty and sloppy, not for indoor use.

When was the last time you heard of anyone filing a warranty claim on their sinktop.  I have never. A sinktop is one of the least likely items in a home to need a warranty claim.   Besides how is it better to pay 3 times the price for a custom sink just to be sure you have a warranty on it.  It makes no sense.

99.9% of the time we win that bet.  Just something OP should be aware of, before cutting.

If the size difference is 7/8" just remove the drywall on each side that gives you an inch then patch up to it, you'll be using a backsplash anyway so that covers any rough work.  Or use an angle grinder to take off 7/8" not too hard given all edges are going to be covered by a backsplash.
